# Update spacemacs packages from the command line

Tags: spacemacs, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a shell function to launch (spac)emacs, update packages, and then restart emacs in daemon mode.

I tried this, but it hangs:

`emacs --daemon && emacsclient -e '(progn (configuration-layer/update-packages))'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

`emacs --daemon -f configuration-layer/update-packages`

Comment: Can you elaborate? Please say something about what that does and why/how it solves the problem.

Comment: Don't know why, but this command stops there when I hit `y` to confirm. @David's answer works without problem.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of trying to start emacs in daemon mode first and asking it to execute the package update, I'd recommend doing that after performing a scripted upgrade of the packages. To update the packages non-interactively, use the following:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el --eval="(configuration-layer/update-packages t)"
```

The key here is the [`--batch` switch](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html) for performing non-interactive operations via the emacs command.

The `-l` switch loads the emacs configuration (including the Spacemacs library and configuration). Without this, emacs would not know what the `configuration-layer/update-packages` function is.

The `--eval` switch passes emacs a function you want to execute. In this case, passing `(configuration-layer/update-packages t)` will call the [`configuration-layer/update-packages`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/core/core-configuration-layer.el#L1669) function from Spacemacs with the argument `t`. Passing the argument skips the interactive package update confirmation; it's only important that the argument be a truthy value.

Note that because of the manner in which Spacemacs updates packages, it will only *prepare* the packages for update when this command is run. The next time that emacs is started, it will actually go through the process of installing the packages, so if you run `emacs --daemon` directly after this function, it may take longer than usual for the system to start up.

This is also why I recommend not starting emacs in daemon mode and having it evaluate the `configuration-layer/update-packages` function: the package updates will only take effect when a new daemon is started.

Comment: If you run the exact same command listed here a second time, Spacemacs will actually perform the update of packages, not just run the preparation.

Answer (score 0):

**To update and quit emacs**

Put this function in your init.el

```
(defun updateandquit ()
  (configuration-layer/update-packages t)
  (spacemacs/kill-emacs))
```

Then call

```
emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el --eval="(updateandquit)"
```